# FB - difference between "Company" and "Internet/Software" page types?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I'm creating a business page which type should be I guess either Company or Internet/Software. Did research but can't find the difference between them. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company is an abstract definition, which can be used in most cases. But if your business is oriented on the Internet/Software then that is what you want to classify it. It will help potential searches and the filters in it, on the facebook platform.

They are all under "Company, Organisation or Institution" type, so the difference will be on how you'll classify your business.